# How to change boot animation?

Tags: plymouth

Is it possible to change to boot animation in 12.04? I know it was possible on 11.10...

if it is, how do you do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Super Boot Manager on ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770172/how-to-install-super-boot-manager-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible, there's a few ways to do it but the best and easiest way is to use Super Boot Manager, not only can you change your boot animation/screen but you can customize GRUB and or BURG. To install open a terminal and input these codes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install buc super-boot-manager
```

Then open super boot manager by searching in the dash for it. Then type your password when asked. Then you can proceed to click on the plymouth manager which controls your boot screen. When the window opens click on theme and you can select which theme you want to use for your boot animation. I personally love the earth sunrise one.

Super boot manager comes with a handful of themes pre-installed so you have plenty to choose from. Additionally there is a preview button which allows you to preview your theme.

When you find a theme you are happy with you can apply changes and enjoy your new boot screen.

Sources: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/super-boot-manager-eases-burg-grub-plymouth-tweaking-pains 
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/super-boot-manger-make-easier-and-intuitive-configuration-of-grub-burg-and-plymouth.html

Comment: The PPA doesn't work anymore, we have to follow this to install it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/770172/how-to-install-super-boot-manager-on-ubuntu-16-04