# Black screen before boot animation Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot

I'm looking for the way to get rid off the black screen during boot and replace it with complete boot animation.

this is my grub file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I tried removing `#` before `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console` it does the trick but altogether with the boot animation it becomes default 14.04 pink with dots animation. And I'm using `Solar` boot animation. When I put `#` back, boot animation appears again though it always lasts for 5 sec and the login screen pops up then.

I use only Nvidia video drivers installed (manually). Nouveau is blacklisted.

What suggestions or solutions could I apply to fix this somehow if possible?

Comment: What about this http://askubuntu.com/questions/201129/how-to-change-boot-animation

Comment: thank you for suggesting but better make sure it's good before advising it:) if look here https://launchpad.net/~ingalex/+archive/ubuntu/super-boot-manager you'll see that the packages stopped delivering since Ubuntu 13.04 so on further distros it may lag and my question not about problem with applying the theme but the black screen after applying it.

Comment: Didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for a while I managed to come to solution in a simple way. It won't remove black screen completely but now it only lasts for 2-3 secs and smoothly jumps to boot screen and you can enjoy your boot animation. To solve this I created `splash` file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
```

then type and save inside the file:

```
FRAMEBUFFER=y
```

choose and update your `default.plymouth`

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth

sudo update-initramfs -u

sudo reboot
```

Done. Now it should look good and normal.