# How to install Super Boot Manager on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have recently upgraded my ubuntu to 16.04. Now I am unable to install super boot manager. I tried to install it using `ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager` ppa.
But everytime it shows `E: Unable to locate package super-boot-manager`.

When I tried to install it using Deb file it shows `Dependency is not satisfiable: buc (>=0.5.2)`.

Is there any way to install this app on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 3):

You must go here :

https://launchpad.net/~ingalex/+archive/ubuntu/super-boot-manager/+packages

Download and install with GDebi the correct version of BUC for your system.

buc_0.5.2-20_i386.deb for 32 Bit or
buc_0.5.2-19_amd64.deb  for 64 Bit

Then you run in the terminal: `apt install super-boot-manager`

Comment: There's nothing for Bionic :'(